# Node js reuse response object

Tags: node.js, http, mobile

First, a little background:

I'm trying to write a mobile phone app that receives data from a nodejs server at an irregular interval. Since this is a mobile app, I would prefer not to poll the server or use a websocket, as I believe that would drain the battery. Instead, I'd like the server to keep track of client IP addresses and push data.

My plan is to have the app send a simple message to the server whenever the phone's connection status changes (i.e, if the phone goes from a wifi connection to mobile data one, send a message since the client IP would have changed). The server would do something like this:

```
app.get('/clientupdate',(req,res)=>{
    // save off the 'res' object here
    res.send('received update');
});
```

Then later, when the server wants to push data to a client, it would retrieve the saved 'res' object and use it to send the data:

```
// retrieve the saved 'res' object here
res.send(data);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The phone would almost certainly use more battery if it had to listen for incoming data from your server than if you would just poll the server at some interval.

Comment: I suppose I could test that, but I figured opening a listen socket would be less expensive that regular polling. Immediate delivery is not vital, but I would like the data to be received by the app in less than 5 minutes. So polling would need to be at least every 5 minutes

Answer (score -1):

Can you instead send both at the same time for example:

```
var reply = JSON.stringify({
    "status": "recieved",
    "error": "null",
    "response": "data"
}));
res.send(reply);
```

Comment: The problem with that is the data might not be available at the time the client sends a connection update. The server needs to cache off the connection info and send data whenever it becomes available

Comment: I am talking about sending success with the data when it is available just to set that no errors occurred and data was found successful